# XPath в XML: вывод данных по принадлежности к критерию

Tags: xml, xpath

Есть база данных с книгами, по ней создан XML-документ: у каждой книги есть publishing_house, нужно с помощью XPath вывести книги для каждого в одном запросе

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/html' href='xslt.html'?>
<books>
    <book>
        <id_book>10004</id_book>
        <name_book>Pride and Prejudice</name_book>
        <id_author>20001</id_author>
        <publishing_house>ABABAGALAMAGA</publishing_house>
        <status>available</status>
        <id_reader>1</id_reader>
        <author>
            <id_author>20001</id_author>
            <name_author>Jane</name_author>
            <surname_author>Austen</surname_author>
        </author>
        <reader>
            <id_reader>1</id_reader>
            <name_reader>Kseniia</name_reader>
            <surname_reader>Govorun</surname_reader>
            <address_reader>Lvivska, 13</address_reader>
            <phone_reader>380962591160</phone_reader>
            <rating_reader>4.3</rating_reader>
        </reader>
    </book>
    <book>
        <id_book>10005</id_book>
        <name_book>Pride</name_book>
        <id_author>20002</id_author>
        <publishing_house>ABABAGALAMAGA</publishing_house>
        <status>available</status>
        <id_reader>2</id_reader>
        <author>
            <id_author>20002</id_author>
            <name_author>Antoine</name_author>
            <surname_author>Saint-Exupery</surname_author>
        </author>
        <reader>
            <id_reader>2</id_reader>
            <name_reader>Alisa</name_reader>
            <surname_reader>Ivanenko</surname_reader>
            <address_reader>Koropatska, 123a</address_reader>
            <phone_reader>380963451160</phone_reader>
        </reader>
    </book>
    <book>
        <id_book>10006</id_book>
        <name_book>Black cat</name_book>
        <id_author>20001</id_author>
        <publishing_house>ABABAGALAMAGA</publishing_house>
        <status>available</status>
        <id_reader>3</id_reader>
        <author>
            <id_author>20001</id_author>
            <name_author>Jane</name_author>
            <surname_author>Austen</surname_author>
        </author>
        <reader>
            <id_reader>3</id_reader>
            <name_reader>Denis</name_reader>
            <surname_reader>Govorun</surname_reader>
            <address_reader>Lvivska, 13</address_reader>
            <phone_reader>380962894160</phone_reader>
            <rating_reader>3.1</rating_reader>
        </reader>
    </book>
</books>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: xml - текстом. что такое "издание" ? publishing house? это издательство

Comment: Да, это и есть издательство

Comment: Выложите xml текстом, а не скриншотом.

Comment: _Есть база данных с книгами_ - вот по базе и нужно делать запросы, она для того и предназначена.

Comment: Нужно именно через XPath

Comment: все книги конкретного издательства можно получить `//book[publishing_house="ABABAGALAMAGA"]/id_book`

Comment: @splash58 а если нужно для каждого издательства, как обобщить, чтобы вывело издательство - книги и так все?

Comment: я работатал только с первым xpath в php, он не позволяет такого сделать одним запросом, можно через `//publishing_house` узнать все издательства и потом последовательно получить для каждого. 2-3й xpath возможно содержит возможности для такой агрегации, но я не могу подсказать

Comment: Судя по второй строке документа, вы используете xslt. Покажите его. И укажите версию: 1 или 2. Группировку по издательствам нужно делать именно в xslt. Или в любом другом языке, с помощью которого обрабатывается этот xml, будь то php, python, java, c#...